# Sparse matrices origins

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, collocation

I am using the sparse matrices provided by the  [University of Florida Sparse Matrix Collection](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/matrices/) and most matrices are accompanied with little description of the problem or discipline from which the matrix was originated, is there a way to find more about each matrix origins, and how it was generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking [Tim Davis](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/publications.html) would be the best approach to finding out.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a *little* bit of context.

Comment: You mean to my answer, or to the matrices? Tim Davis is the person who runs, to the best of my knowledge, the matrix collection project. He should be the first person to contact when asking about the matrices in this collection. Nobody will have more information than he has.